# How to prevent 3rd part services from using my API?

Tags: security, configuration

I have developed a front-end interface using Aja(AngularJS) and HTML5. Right now, I send an HTTP get request to my backend server which returns some data based on the GET parameters.

Since the URL is exposed in the Javascript file, I believe anyone could just use the URL to create there own API to fetch the data. How can I prevent such things ?

One way I could think of is that now instead of directly sending the request to the backend server, an application server could be used (hosting the HTML as well). The Ajax request would then be sent to this server (PHP script ?) which would in turn forward the request to the backend server and return the result to the UI. To prevent 3rd party services, I can disable cross origin requests on my application server.

Is this the correct way to solve my problem or are there better ways to do this? I am concerned that this would unnecessarily create another hop (internal though) for requests.

Note: The backend is running Apache Tomcat

Comment: So then you would be writing an API that accesses the real API...and they can just emulate that one...

Comment: Actually, yes. That's why I am looking for better suggestions. I haven't done any kind of professional web development before

Comment: you fix that , then people use screen scrapers to grab the data. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to prevent applications other than mine to access the data

Comment: unfortunately, that's not an easy task.  If people can access the data through your program, they can reverse engineer how it works and build their own.  What you want is DRM, and if you can come up with an unbreakable DRM scheme, you could patent it and to retire to your own private island.

Comment: Is it worth pursuing it then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In APIs that are not open to the world the user has to authenticate first in order to use it, see for example https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication or http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/ -> Authorization

Comment: This is true, but also realize authentication built into your software (ie part of the program, not input from the user) can be easily copied by someone trying to make their own application to use the API.